# MVC 3: How to Mock an instance of WebViewPage<T>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I'm currently using the Rhino Mocks mocking framework. How do you mock an instance of [WebViewPageBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg402107%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) AND its Model with Rhino Mocks or any other mocking framework? When I run the following unit test, an exception is thrown when attempting to access the WebViewPageBase.Model property.

```
        var repo = new Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository();

        System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<Tuple<string>>> page = repo.DynamicMock<System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<Tuple<string>>>>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(page.Model);//exception thrown, not a fail on Assert
```

Would this be more easily accomplished with a different mocking framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has a great write-up on mocking MVC 3 classes with Rhino here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to get the view page this way as it won't have a model etc because it has not all been setup.

More typically you would test the controller and inspects its return value which would contain the rendered html if you want to check that.

Assuming you really do want to unit test this, then I don't see anything intrinsically wrong with your code. You could try Moq instead of Rhino which is what I use.

This question may also be pertinent to your issue without how Rhino handles abstract classes:

[Mock abstract class default behaviour with Rhino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620894/mock-abstract-class-default-behaviour-with-rhino)